# access denied when accessing mysql database through glassfish server

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish, persistence

I'm following a tutorial which uses GlassFish to access a mysql database in NetBeans. The problem is I'm getting this error

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a
>   connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

when I try to deploy my app. I understand I need to add the password to the configuration so that GlassFish can establish the connection. The problem is I'm not sure where to include it within the persistence file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.mycompany_MyApp_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/creditpurchase</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit properties in glassfish admin console. Resources->JDBC->Connections Pools->your_connection_pool in Additional Properties tab. You can add property with name password. take a look [here](https://computingat40s.wordpress.com/how-to-setup-a-jdbc-connection-in-glassfish/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it here:

```
C:\Code\Java\Glassfish\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml
```

Change the properties within the **jdbc-connection-pool** tag